# Django is it safe csrf middleware token shows up in url?

Tags: django, csrf

when making GET requests, I've noticed that my csrf tokens gets appended to my url. Is this safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django doesn't check the CSRF token for GET requests. If you have any forms with `method="get"`, you should remove the `{% csrf_token %}` tag.

While you are doing that, double check that GET requests are side-effect free (i.e. that they don't change any data). If they aren't, then keep the CSRF token and change the view/form to use a POST request instead.

If the CSRF token is included in URLs, then it might be stored somewhere e.g. server logs. If an attacker got the token, then they could use it to get around Django's CSRF protection.

See the [Django CSRF docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/) for more information.

Comment: cool, thanks for clarifying :) I'm curious what the implications are if a potential attacker got access to someone's csrf token. You can still access the csrf token either way through the console

Comment: You can see your own CSRF token through your browser tools, but an attacker doesn't have access to it (or if they did, then you have bigger problems). Once an attacker knows your CSRF token, they can create a `<form>` that contains the token, and try to trick you into clicking on it.